# I need help placing objects on surface normals

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

My problem is as follows:
I've got a simple tool to merge a .max file.

What i would like to to is after the merge function, i want to automaticly place the object on the surfaces in my scene (by tracking the mouse i guess).

I did some researh and i came up with some tools that let you manually select the object to be placed,  and the object where it should be placed on. But i never found a script to do this automaticly after the merge function.

Mymaxscript skills are not good enough to do this myself unfortunately :O

i need help friends!

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand 100% what you are trying to do.  However, hopefully this can help you:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-84E24969-C175-4389-B9A6-3B2699B66785